# Controller action not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using web api in my application. Web api 2 routing is working fine but the controller action routing is not found.

[image]

this is my global cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
    }
}
```

Route Config

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Web api config

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultDataApi",
            routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Default/Login.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

        authManager.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see the controller?

Comment: I add the controller. It is a simple controller. when i call the controller without action by default it goes to Index action. But when mention the action after the controller it shows not found error. even the Index action also shows the not found error.

Comment: I think the problem is "Focus" part in your url. Where does it come from?

Comment: Project Url:http://localhost/Focus .  i defined it in Local IIS

Answer (score 1):

Change your Route config as

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Focus/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Since "Focus" is defined in iis, it might or might not work with it. Please try, i don't have envoirment to test it right now.

Comment: Thank you it solve my problem.  url: "{controller}/{action}",

Answer (score 0):

Your url http://localhost/Focus/Login/Logout doesn't match the pattern of routeTemplate "Api/{controller}/{id}" in WebApiConfig. Try to match your url to the pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you deusExCore I solve the problem

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    }
}
```